# Do android.opengl.Matrix operations allocate objects on the heap as they execute?

Tags: android, performance, heap-memory, opengl-es-2.0

I've started writing an OpenGLES20 application using Android.  I've ended up writing all the matrix manipulation functions from scratch because I'm scared of allocating new objects every time a frame is rendered and I'm worried that if I use the built in functionality it may create and destroy objects.

I'm worried about this because I know there is limited heap space and I know that garbage collection can be a performance hit.

Looking at the signatures of the classes in `android.opengl.Matrix` (for example `multiplyMM`) and with a little knowledge of how matrix operations worked, it looked likely that new objects would be allocated and destroyed as they did their business.

I've googled around but haven't been able to find anything which points me one way or the other so, a few questions:
1. Am I right to focus so heavily on what happens when frames are rendered?
2. Am I right to worry about object creation/heap management or should I just get on with it?
3. Do `android.opengl.Matrix` operation even suffer from what I've been worrying about?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the android source code for that: http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/opengl/Matrix.java/?v=source

And yes, you should worry about creating objects each frame, read this: http://traxnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/android-game-development-tipstricks/

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I didn't realise you could get at the android source code (which will be very handy) and your blog I will follow!